# Mono output with romplayer

Tags: audiokit

I'm building an app using Romplayer with an esx24 instrument using stereo samples and 44/24-bit resolution.   App is working but output appears to be mono when using my stereo samples.  I looked at the included sample sets and they are 16-bit mono.  Is there a way to make Romplayer output in 44-24 stereo?

Comment: That's interesting. Stereo samples should playback in stereo. As, AKMIDISampler is based on AVAudioUnitSampler. I used mono files in the repo as the TX81z is a mono synth. And, mono files take up less room...

Comment: Double checking, if you reload your EXS file into Logic, does it play in stereo there? Please keep me posted on your app- matthew@audiokitpro.com Hope you get it working! \m/

Comment: Thanks for the response..just checked and in Logic the ESX file plays in stereo using ESX24

Comment: If you want to zip up an EXS file you are having trouble with and email it to me, I'll see if I can troubleshoot it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to play stereo sample sources. In the signal chain in the Conductor.swift file, the AutoPan effect converts the input to mono. One can play stereo EXS files by bypassing this effect.

I have added an AutoPan bypass to ROM Player Github repo now, illustrating this. Users can fully bypass the AutoPan with the corresponding toggle button.

The following commit adds this functionality:
https://github.com/AudioKit/ROMPlayer/commit/59fb808bc93e085c36389f5f864f164aa76697a6

ROM Player will now play Stereo EXS files out-of-the-box.